# Upload on init wwwroot in blazor wasm hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Im trying to find a way that when I start a Hosted (ASP.NET) Blazor project, when the client init, all the files in wwwroot will load. I dont want to file upload only when needed, I want all the files to download to the browser in the beginning. So after the long initialization time I will have all the files.
I understand that it may take a lot of unnecessary resources but im willing to pay the price.

Comment: I think you should look somewhere around PWA offline support..